# react-select as omni search box

Tags: react-select

I have a rails backend doing fulltext search on my contact's info, including their emails, phone number, etc. And the

```
  class ContactServiceController < ApplicationController
    def search
      query = User.search_for_contacts(params[:query])
      @contacts = query.results
      render :index
    end      
  end
```

it returns an array of contacts with just the first and last name.

```
[{first: 'John', last:'doe'}, {first: 'jane', last: 'doe'}]
```

with react-select, I was hoping that if a user put in john@doe.com, the returned records will be shown in the dropdown menu, I understand that it is not likely I can highlight the correct item in that list, but it'd be nice to just show it. Is it possible?

Here is my react-select component

```
    <Select.Async
        name="contact-select"
        value={id}
        loadOptions={getOptions || this.getOptions}
        onChange={this.onChange}
        allowCreate={true}
    />

    const prepareContactsData = contacts => 
      map(contacts, (contact) => 
        (
          {
            label: contact.full,
            value: contact.id,
          }
        )
    )


    const getOptions = (query, callback) => {
      if(!query.length){
        return callback(null, [])
      }
      return contactServiceApi
              .search({query})
              .then( data => {
                callback(null, 
                  {
                    options: prepareContactsData(data.contacts)
                  }
                )
              })
    }
```

thank you!